# TFS not accessible remotely after reboot of server

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, tfs, port, firewall

We have been working with TFS 2012 (Windows Server 2008 R2) successfully for a couple of months. Just now, I did a repair of .NET Framework 4.5 on the TFS machine (I was missing some files for a build) and did a reboot of the machine - the first in a long time.

And now:

- I cannot access TFS from its remote IP-address as I could before the reboot (http://*ipaddress-numbers*:8080/tfs). Not from my local machine, and not logged in to the machine itself. Not accessible by Visual Studio, nor browser.
- I can access it through http://*localhost*:8080/tfs logged in to the machine
- From what I see, the binding to port 8080 is correct in IIS, and the port is also open for all in Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the reboot the network connection had changed from being classed as Private to Public. And so the firewall was set to not let through Public connections to the TFS.

I did the troubleshooting by disabling the firewall and seeing that the connection was let through...

[image]